# Python SQL data import - Backslash removed in the process of data import to data base

Tags: python, sql, data-import

I am importing into data base string values, the problem is that in the process of import backslashes are removed. So where i had "\\" in data base appear the following "\" and where i had "\" i get "". Any assistance is very much appreciated.

The import method code is:

```
         cnxn = MySQLdb.connect(host=entry_server_value, user=entry_user_value, passwd=entry_password_value, db=entry_dbName_value)
    columns_list = ""
    for column in columns:
        columns_list = columns_list + column
        if columns.index(column) is not (len(columns)-1):
            columns_list = columns_list + ','

    for line in csv.reader(open(full_file_path)):
        cursor = cnxn.cursor()
        values = ""
        for x in line:
            values = values + "'" + str(x) + "'"
            if line.index(x) is not (len(line)-1):
                values = values + ','

        # In case last character is comma remove 
        if values[-1:] is ',':
            values = values[:-1]

        mysql_q = 'SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;insert into ' + entry_dbName_value + '.' + file_name + \
              ' (' + columns_list + ') VALUES(' + values + ');SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;'
        cursor.execute("%r"%mysql_q)
        cursor.close()
        cnxn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

MySQLdb (and other packages that conform to Python's DB-API standard) provides a parameter substitution method that takes care of string escaping automatically.  It's better to use this than to try to manually construct values for insertion (it's also safer, if you're inserting data from an untrusted source).

For MySQLdb, the substitution string is '%s'.

You create the statement like this:

`stmt = """INSERT INTO mytable (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s);"""`

And execute like this:

`cursor.execute(stmt, ('foo', 'bar'))`

or you can insert multiple rows in a single statement:

`cursor.executemany(stmt, [('foo', 'bar'), ('baz', 'quux')])`

Your code should look something like this:

```
mysql_q = 'SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;insert into ' + entry_dbName_value + '.' + file_name + \
          ' (' + columns_list + ') VALUES({});SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;'
for line in csv.reader(open(full_file_path)):
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    subs = ','.join('%s' for _ in line)
    stmt = mysql_q.format(subs)
    cursor.execute(stmt, line)
    cursor.close()
    cnxn.commit()
```